# Problemas al leer la base de datos en mi programa Python Sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite3

estoy creando un toplevel donde hay entry, y botones, en la cual un boton tiene la funcionalidad de leer la base de datos, pero, me aparece un error:

File "raiz.pyw", line 110, in leer
    miCursor.execute("SELECT * FROM DATOSPACIENTES WHERE CI=" + miCI.get())
    sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: V22342421

La base de datos, la cual ya fue creada con exito, e incluso me funciona otro toplevel que se usa para agregar pacientes

```
   def conexionBBDD():

    miConexion=sqlite3.connect("Pacientes")

    miCursor=miConexion.cursor()

      try:

            miCursor.execute('''
            CREATE TABLE DATOSPACIENTES (
            NPACIENTE INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
            NOMBRE_USUARIO VARCHAR (50),
            CI VARCHAR (20),
            SEXO VARCHAR (10),
            FECHA_NACIMIENTO VARCHAR (10),
            EDAD VARCHAR (10),
            DIRECCION VARCHAR (100),
            EMAIL VARCHAR (50),
            TELEFONO VARCHAR (15),
            HISTORIAL VARCHAR (1000000))''')

        messagebox.showinfo("Base de Datos", "Base de datos para pacientes, ha sido creada con éxito.")

      except:

            messagebox.showwarning("¡Atención!", "La base de datos ya existe")
```

El código es el siguiente:

LA FUNCIÓN

```
 def leer():

    miConexion=sqlite3.connect("Pacientes")

    miCursor=miConexion.cursor()

    miCursor.execute("SELECT * FROM DATOSPACIENTES WHERE CI=" + miCI.get())

    elPaciente=miCursor.fetchall()

     for paciente in elPaciente:

        miPaciente.set(paciente[0])
        miNombre.set(paciente[1])
        miCI.set(paciente[2])
        miSexo.set(paciente[3])
        miFechaNac.set(paciente[4])
        miEdad.set(paciente[5])
        miDireccion.set(paciente[6])
        miEmail.set(paciente[7])
        miTelefono.set(paciente[8])
        textoHistorial.insert(1.0, usuario[9])

    miConexion.commit()
```

Y ESTA ES LA FUNCION QUE HACE EL MENU, AL DARLE CLICK APARECE UN TOPLEVEL

```
 def BuscarPaciente():

    win1=Toplevel()
    win1.title("BUSCAR PACIENTE")
    win1.iconbitmap("controlab.ico")
    win1.resizable(0,0)
    win1.geometry('580x400')
    win1.focus_set()
    win1.grab_set()

    entry0=Entry(win1, textvariable=miPaciente)
    entry0.grid(row=0, column=1)
    entry0=Label(win1, text="N° PACIENTE :")
    entry0.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
    entry0.config(justify="center")


    entry1=Entry(win1, textvariable=miNombre)
    entry1.grid(row=1, column=1)
    label1=Label(win1, text="Nombre :")
    label1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="e", padx=10, pady=10)

    entry2=Entry(win1, textvariable=miCI)
    entry2.grid(row=1, column=3)
    label2=Label(win1, text="C.I :")
    label2.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky="e", padx=10, pady=10)

    entry3=Entry(win1, textvariable=miSexo)
    entry3.grid(row=2, column=1)
    label3=Label(win1, text="Sexo :")
    label3.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="e", padx=10, pady=10)

    entry4=Entry(win1, textvariable=miFechaNac)
    entry4.grid(row=2, column=3)
    label4=Label(win1, text="Fecha Nac. :")
    label4.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky="e", padx=10, pady=10)

    entry5=Entry(win1, textvariable=miEdad)
    entry5.grid(row=3, column=1)
    label5=Label(win1, text="Edad :")
    label5.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="e", padx=10, pady=10)


    entry6=Entry(win1, textvariable=miDireccion, width=62)
    entry6.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=3)
    label6=Label(win1, text="Dirección :")
    label6.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky="e", padx=10, pady=10)


    entry7=Entry(win1, textvariable=miEmail)
    entry7.grid(row=5, column=1)
    label7=Label(win1, text="Email :")
    label7.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky="e", padx=10, pady=10)


    entry8=Entry(win1, textvariable=miTelefono)
    entry8.grid(row=5, column=3)
    label8=Label(win1, text="Telefono :")
    label8.grid(row=5, column=2, sticky="e", padx=10, pady=10)

    LabelHistorial=Label(win1, text="Historial Clínico :")
    LabelHistorial.grid(row=6, column=0, sticky="e", padx=10, pady=10)
    textoHistorial=Text(win1, width=46, height=5)
    textoHistorial.grid(row=6, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, columnspan=3)



    # ------------SCROLL PARA EL HISTORIAL ----------------------

    scrollVert=Scrollbar(win1, command=textoHistorial.yview)
    scrollVert.grid(row=6, column=4, sticky="nsew")

    textoHistorial.config(yscrollcommand=scrollVert.set)


  # ------------------ BOTONES  ----------------------------

    botonCrear=Button(win1, text="Buscar", command=leer)
    botonCrear.grid(row=7, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
```

Les agradezco de antemano, esto es un proyecto que estoy haciendo para mi hermana, soy nuevo en programación y apenas estoy comenzando a ver cursos pero como estoy haciendo algo por mi cuenta y solo tomando algunas cosas de los buenos cursos que tengo, me topo con algunos errores,

Saludos!

Comment: Creo que simplemente no le pusiste las comillas simples en el WHERE... `miCursor.execute("SELECT * FROM DATOSPACIENTES WHERE CI='" + miCI.get()+"'")`

Comment: Gracias, si me logra leer todo menos el texto del historial, tuve problemas anteriormente con este texto largo,

Comment: me sale el siguiente error:

NameError: name 'textoHistorial' is not defined

Comment: LISTO!!!!!!!!!!!!!!, mil gracias, ya resolvi con un Lambda, adicional me fije que tenia un error en la busqueda, habia puesto usuario y era paciente. Tampoco me leía, no se si sea la forma correcta usar un lambda, pero, de que funciona .. funciona JAJAJAJA.